# How to type a dispatch function in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I would expect this to pass typechecking but it does not.

Is it there a way to get this well typed in Typescript?

```
const hh = {
  a: (_: { type: 'a' }) => '',
  b: (_: { type: 'b' }) => '',
} as const;

export function dispatch<
  Arg extends Parameters<(typeof hh)[keyof typeof hh]>[0],
>(arg: Arg) {
  const h = hh[arg.type];
  h(arg);
}
```

The goal of the function `dispatch()` is to take a valid argument to one of the functions stored in `hh` and call that function with that argument.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nl8Q5N) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you @wonderflame, I was able to make your approach work for my use case! If anyone is interested, [here](https://tsplay.dev/w29xzW) is a slightly less simplified working example of what I needed.

Comment: Should I write an answer?

Comment: I think that I have all I need, but if you write an answer I will accept it. If you do write an answer, it'd be great if you could explain why the original approach fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is unable to handle the "correlated union types" described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), however, there is an officially suggested workaround suggested in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) that requires to have some map type which will be the single source of truth for the functions and dispatch arguments.

Let's create this type:

```
type ActionMap = {
  a: {
    payload?: {};
  };
  b: {
    payload?: {};
  };
};
```

I've assumed you are using `redux` actions, thus I added optional payload property.

Now, let's type `hh` using this type and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
const hh: {
  [K in keyof ActionMap]: (action: ActionMap[K] & { type: K }) => string;
} = {
  a: (action) => '',
  b: (action) => '',
};
```

And another one for the dispatch arguments, however here we are going to return a union by default and specific arguments if the generic argument that represents which action is being dispatched will be passed:

```
type DispatchArgs<T extends keyof ActionMap = keyof ActionMap> = {
  [K in T]: { type: K } & ActionMap[K];
}[T];
```

Usage:

```
export function dispatch<ActionType extends keyof ActionMap>(
  arg: DispatchArgs<ActionType>,
) {
  const h = hh[arg.type];

  h(arg); // no error
}
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYFkCGYoF4oDeAsAFBRSYBchp55YmIANspgCYD81BAvgNy0o-QQCNug+oxbsuhYWSECS80nDQBnYFAAW28QoDaAaSiJUUANYQQyAGawEKDNgC61ABSZHaavCRosMGMXKAAyQihQSGoTHgBKPAA+KE0AJzMAcyUePBoFKihPb1QE3GSAcnKAGlEPL38SpKhKmuUlUijoABFEdQZgOG0YVIz1AB4AFSgIAA9gCFQ2dUtrOwcGwNyrG3s-J0Dk-GJDEzMoCbcIzpihMPX97GDsgwv2klmwZFStWwBXVGKUDYvX6gzGezQE3A0Fm80Wy22awhzjAiXcgkwI2oPT6mAGQxG42RUMgiVaCWO5DUqE0OlyugMmIyADpOi43uRtJ4RnFsqQgA)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: https://tsplay.dev/we8MYW

This was surprisingly tricky. I'll run down my thoughts:

I took the liberty to abstract the `hh` map implementation by making a create function that returns a specific dispatch function for a `hh`. I did this so we can check the `hh` first, if it confirms to your imposed rules.

```
function createDispatch(hh: {[key in string]: (_: { type: key }) => any}) {
  return dispatch(arg: { type: key }) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This was my first approach, which didn't work as key gets rationalized to be just `string`, which doesn't suffice. You can however map over an object if you take `keyof ob` as type for the key instead of `string`.

So I made a such a Generic type, taking in a union of possible keys and outputting an object where the keys and values respectively are the same.

```
type ExactValue<Of extends string> = {
  [K in Of]: K;
};

type TestExactValue = ExactValue<"a" | "b"> // { a: "a", b: "b" }
```

We could then just map over this again to create an object that confirms to your imposed rules for `hh`.

```
type HH<O> = { readonly [key in keyof O]: (_: { type: O[key]}) => any }

type TestHH = HH<TestExactValue> // { a: (_: { type: "a" }) => any, b: (_: { type: "b" }) => any }
```

Then we just implement this into our `createDispatch` function.

```
function createDispatcher<Key extends keyof typeof hh, O extends ExactValue<Key>, WW extends { readonly [key in keyof O]: (_: { type: O[key]}) => any }>(hh: WW) {
```

Then the `dispatch` function itself theoretically just has to check if you input one of the correct arguments, so `{ type: Key }` or `Parameters<WW[Key]>[0]`. However, the latter one does not work on the line where you pluck `h` (`const h = hh[arg.type]`), so (as the argument structure is fixed anyway) let's go with the first one.

I figured that you maybe also want the correct return types, so I tried to do that as well. By taking `ReturnType<typeof h>` it returned the union of all possible return types. Adding a  `& { type: MyKey }` where `MyKey` is just generic of `dispatch` extending `string` or `Key` makes it work as expected. I cannot comprehensively explain why, though. So just take it as a gift from TS.

The full code would be:

```
type ExactValue<Of extends string> = {
  [K in Of]: K;
};


function createDispatcher<Key extends keyof typeof hh, O extends ExactValue<Key>, WW extends { readonly [key in keyof O]: (_: { type: O[key]}) => any }>(hh: WW) {
  return function dispatch<MyKey extends Key>(arg: { type: Key } & { type: MyKey }) {
    const h = hh[arg.type]
    return h(arg as any) as ReturnType<typeof h>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MaximilianMairinger, but I think the last line line of your solution should have been `return h(arg) as ReturnType<typeof h>`, but that does not pass typechecking.